# How generate charts from data set and save as image?

Tags: c#

I need to generate pie charts, column charts ,bar charts according to given data set in server side and save them as image. I could add data set to excel sheet and generate chart in a excel sheet and export as image . Other than that method are there any freely available c# libraries to generate charts and save as image ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` class in the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` to generate charts.

Then use the `SaveImage` method to, well, save the image.